# Abstract approach to the total electric force on a charged rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

Suppose we have a 1-dimensional system (x-axis) consisting of rod of finite length $l$ and arbitrary charge density of $\lambda(x)$ at rest extending from the origin to $x=l$. And now, suppose we have a distant static source of electric field (the generation of which we do not care about) along the x-axis and we would like to calculate the total force acting on the rod due to the electric field:

$$ F_{tot}=\int_{0-\epsilon}^{l+\epsilon} \lambda(x)E(x)dx \tag{1}$$

where we have extended the integration by a factor of $\epsilon$ which should not affect the integral since $\lambda(x)$ is zero. We know that we can express the static electric field as the gradient of a potential ($\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla} \phi=-\partial_x \phi$, since we are in 1-dimension) so our integral becomes:

\begin{align}
F_{tot}&=\int_{0-\epsilon}^{l+\epsilon} \lambda(x)E(x)dx \\
&=\int_{0-\epsilon}^{l+\epsilon} \lambda(x)(-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})dx \\
&= -\lambda(x)\phi(x) \vert_{0-\epsilon}^{l+\epsilon} +\int_{0-\epsilon}^{l+\epsilon} \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x}\phi dx \tag{2}
\end{align}

Now, here's where I'm getting super confused about my logic/results. Suppose we have a charge density that is constant, $\lambda(x)=\lambda_o$, I conclude the following:

A. The expression for the total electric force from Eq.1 is non-zero:

$$ F_{tot}=\int_{0-\epsilon}^{l+\epsilon} \lambda_o E(x)dx \ne 0$$

B. The boundary term of Eq. 2 is zero since $\lambda$ at the bounds of integration is zero and we are left with an integral which is equal to zero because $\lambda$ is constant:

$$ F_{tot}=\int_{0-\epsilon}^{l+\epsilon} \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x}\phi dx=0$$

My questions are:

1. For arbitrary, non-constant charge distributions ($\lambda(x)$), how do we interpret the fact that the total force due to the electric field is proportional to the variation of the charge density in Eq. 2? Eq.1 makes complete sense to me in that the electric field is weighted by the all the charges along the rod. But, I'm having a lot of trouble conceptualizing how the derivative of the charge distribution comes into play.
2. For a constant charge distribution, the total force is zero! Unless we have to take into account the fact that at the end points of the rod there is an infinite variation from $\lambda_o$ to zero? If so, how does the slope of the charge density at the ends determine the complete electric on the rod (like that of Eq.1)?

Comment: Check if you might use the step function $\:\theta(x)\:$. For example in case of constant $\:\lambda(x)=\lambda_0\:,\quad x\in [0,l]$ : $$\lambda(x)=\lambda_0\left[\theta(x)-\theta(x-l)\right]$$  Then you make use of the property that the derivative of the $\theta$-function is the Dirac $\delta$-function.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that and that would give us a non-zero force. But, then how would one address question #1 in conceptually relating the derivative of the charge distribution to the total force?